# How to convert this format to datetime in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, format, valueerror

My data is in this format Feb 1, 2021 @ 01:22:01.602, I am using this to convert it to datetime:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(str(01:22:01.602), '%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Gives me the error: ValueError:'object' did not match format '%H:%M:%S.%f'

Comment: in your example, `str(01:22:01.602)` won't work. `datetime.datetime.strptime("01:22:01.602", '%H:%M:%S.%f')` works perfectly fine on the other hand.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> date_string = 'Feb 1, 2021 @ 01:22:01.602'
>>> datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(date_string,'%b %d, %Y @ %H:%M:%S.%f')
>>> datetime_obj
datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 1, 1, 22, 1, 602000)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following would help you:

```
import datetime

date_in_special_format="Feb 1, 2021 @ 01:22:01.602"
merkki=date_in_special_format.index('@')
time_in_special_format=date_in_special_format[merkki+2:len(date_in_special_format)]

clocktime=datetime.datetime.strptime(time_in_special_format, '%H:%M:%S.%f').strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f')

print(clocktime)
```